# How come this tag [romantic] is not needed on a question when the question is specially about romantic films?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I am confused about rejection of the below edit:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25680

I can understand that the question is about casting of a movie. However, the OP seems to be explicity interested in romantic movies. In fact, if we consider comedy movies, there is very much change where we will find couples with different heights just for fun.

So I want to understand if it is not good practice to tag questions with genre tags when it is specifically asked by OP for the same. There are certain people who are experts for a particular genre.

Comment: Related discussion [How to use genre tags?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-use-genre-tags), [The future of Genre tags](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/the-future-of-genre-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that the question asks about movies from a specific genre. But there were two problems with this that probably added to a downright rejection of this suggested edit:

- The primary reason for rejecting the edit was that **the tag you gave was just wrong**. The tag [romantic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romantic) was a newly created tag, while there already exists the tag [romance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance) that actually describes the genre (and does so in a grammatically more consistent way, as it's a noun and not an adjective), which should also have popped up when you started to type "roman...".
- Another problem I saw was admittedly more a problem with the question, which seemed to have a rather narrow and subjective definition of what a "romatic pairing" is, disregarding valid romantic pairings given in answers just because the respective movie is a romatic *comedy* instead of a *pure* romance (whatever that even is, but certainly not *Top Gun* anyway). This is admittedly not your fault but that of the question and my attitude towards it, but it added to the problem of tagging it with a specific genre tag in as much that I didn't bother to improve the incorrect tag you chose but rather settled for just rejecting the edit and be done with it.

In retrospect however, I would agree that the asker is specifically concentrating on the genre of romantic movies, even if I might not agree with that premise. So seeing that the primary problem of the edit was just taking the wrong tag, I'd be inclined to approve the edit if you'd be kind enough to resubmit it with the correct [romance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance) tag.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, somehow i didn't used romance tag as i found romantic appropiate . May be not being native english speaker, here in India we use word romantic in context of movie. Infact,  rarely use romance word in any context, we use other hindi words. And regarding submiting edit with correct tag, simply you can add that tag, as your edit  will not need the approval. So why go by long way that i will edit and you approve.

Comment: *"So why go by long way that i will edit and you approve."* - Because, frankly, I don't really want to add that tag. ;-P (Or maybe I just want to give you the +2 for an approved edit.)

Comment: Edited because i want people to reply related to romanctic movies as questioner wants answer from same.

Comment: @Panther Then feel free to add the tag if you think it's appropriate. I simply don't want to touch that question, which doesn't mean I will reject the edit if it uses the correct tag.

Comment: *"May be not being native english speaker, here in India we use word romantic in context of movie. Infact, rarely use romance word in any context"* - Sure, but in this case you might be talking about a `romantic-movie`.  Romantic alone doesn't seem sufficient as tags are usually nouns, especially when it's about genres. A tag that's an adjective sounds incomplete.